# Am I required to work if I am not being paid in New York?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, payment

My pay period will start on August 22nd, however my employer wants me to come in on August 19th. Since this is outside the pay period am I required to work?

Comment: Is this for a new job?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch No it is a job I am continuing. Does this make a difference?